# Threads usage in Ruby: is there a way to speed up execution with parallelism?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, performance

I am testing [Threads](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Thread.html) in Ruby at the moment, but don't understand: if they are actually work in MRI or not? By working threads I mean ability to execute them in parallel to speed up application.

Here is my example:

```rb
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report do
    threads = []

    thread_1 = Thread.new { (1..50_000_000).inject { |sum, n| sum + n } }
    thread_2 = Thread.new { (1..100_000_000).inject { |sum, n| sum + n } }

    threads << thread_1
    threads << thread_2

    threads.each { |t| t.join }
  end
end


Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report do
    (1..50_000_000).inject { |sum, n| sum + n }
    (1..100_000_000).inject { |sum, n| sum + n }
  end
end
```

Benchmark results(computer does have 2 cores):

```
       user     system      total        real
  14.040000   0.030000  14.070000 ( 14.096566)
       user     system      total        real
  13.970000   0.030000  14.000000 ( 14.023680)
```

As you can see, with threads, program execution is even slower. I assume that threads are being executed coherently(by `threads.each { |t| t.join }` ). Is there a way to run them simultaneously? Or any other way to speed up ruby-script execution on multi-core computer?

I will appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: the way increase production of app is to use processes i.e. fork/exec, because of global lock even on many cores, in MRI (std ruby)

Comment: Nope, threads in MRI are crippled. They can do concurrent I/O, but no concurrent calculations.

Comment: Use jruby or rubinius :)

Comment: Good points, thanks. I will try out forks. I can't use jruby since app already in production with MRI.

Comment: haha, many russians got into the thread, and told each other =)

Comment: *Every* Ruby implementation in production use today can run threads in parallel, *except* one (YARV). If you insist on using the *only one* which can't, then there's not much you can do.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I have read your answer on similar question, but there you said it is only available for JRuby. Can you provide a code example or maybe link where can I read more about parallel execution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Ruby Language Specification does not guarantee that threads can actually run in parallel. The vast majority of Ruby implementations are indeed capable of running threads in parallel (e.g. Rubinius, JRuby, IronRuby, MacRuby, Ruby.NET), but MRI and YARV can't.

MRI uses green threads, which it schedules itself, but never schedules in parallel. YARV uses native threads which are scheduled by the OS, but protects them with a Giant VM Lock (GVL) to prevent them from being scheduled in parallel. Note that for both MRI and YARV, this only applies to *Ruby* threads. MRI can run multiple C threads in parallel to its single interpreter thread, and will do so for I/O, for example; also, C extensions can run multiple C threads in parallel. And YARV only prevents its threads from entering the VM, but when they are in the C library or waiting on I/O or running some C code from a C extension, they may run in parallel.

JRuby and IronRuby use JVM threads and CLI threads, respectively. There is nothing within JRuby and IronRuby which prevents them from running in parallel, but it depends on the JVM or CLI implementation you are using. Not all JVMs do support running threads in parallel, although most mainstream ones are capable of that. And, of course, your operating system needs to support it as well, and you need to actually have multiple cores.

Answer (score 3):

MRI has [Global Interpreter Lock (aka GIL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock), thus one process can execute only one thread at the moment.

Comment: MRI Ruby before 1.9 - provide [`Green Threads`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads).

Comment: @Зелёный: the page you linked to says "Ruby before version 1.9". 1.8 - green threads, yes. 1.9 and up - real threads.

Comment: i have very old books about Ruby, my bad )).